Excel shutdown when macro executed
I wrote short macro. It updates Power query table and after that pivot table which source is power query table mentioned above.
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").ListObjects("Summary").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll


If I run it normaly on the next started macro excel shut down
If I run it step by step on the next started macro excel NOT shut down
I need excel not ot shutdown

please see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example so people can reproduce your issue . Also check out the tour, and help center

A shot in the dark... Is Summary sheet hidden?
